# simulate hover effect in Fancytree

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancytree

I'm searching for an option to trigger the mouse-hover effect for a Fancytree element. Tried it with mouseover/mouseout and with mouseover:

```
$(fancytreeObj.getNodeByKey("1").li).trigger("mouseenter")
$(fancytreeObj.getNodeByKey("1").li).trigger("mouseover")

$(fancytreeObj.getNodeByKey("1").span).trigger("mouseenter")
$(fancytreeObj.getNodeByKey("1").span).trigger("mouseover")
```

The span:mouseenter trigger at least fires the connected hooks but not the hover-effect (highlighting) of the entry.

Any idea how to do this?

Cheers,
Matthias

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your code unless you do that, I am guessing this question will be closed very soon. :) :)

Comment: Hi :) I added a small snippet :)

Comment: The hover effect is implemented using CSS rules (`:hover` pseudoselector). If you want to simulate that, you could add a new class to the node and add a new CSS rule for it.

Comment: Many thanks for your hint!

adding a class which takes the `span.fancytree-title:hover` style works like a charme:

`span.fancytree-title:hover, .fancytree-title-hovered{
  background-color: #F2F7FD;
  border-color: #B8D6FB;
}`